# Showing that given vector is orthogonal to given space.

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

> Let $r_{1},\dots,r_{n-1}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be linearly independent vectors. Let $v_{1},\dots,v_{n}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R} ^{n}$. Define
>
> $$r_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\det\left(v_{i},r_{1},\dots,r_{n-1}\right)v_{i}$$
>
> show that $r_{n}$ is orthogonal to the space spanned by $r_{1},\dots,r_{n-1}$. What is the geometric meaning of the length of $r_{n}$?

I'm pretty lost.. I know this is supposed to generalize the vector product in $\mathbb{R}^3$ in some way, but I'm not sure how to show the orthogonality. Even for the (hopefully) easier case of $v_i=(0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots,0)$ (where the $1$ is on the $i$th variable) I have no idea...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
\left<r_n,r_j\right>&=\sum_{i=1}^n\left<v_i,r_j\right>\det(v_i,r_1,\cdots,r_{n-1})\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\det(\left<v_i,r_j\right>v_i,r_1,\cdots,r_{n-1})\\
&=\det(\sum_{i=1}^n\left<v_i,r_j\right>v_i,r_1,\cdots,r_{n-1})\\
&=\det(r_j,r_1,\cdots,r_{n-1})\\
&=0\quad \text{  (for $j\not=n$)}
\end{align}
Where the second and the third equalities follow from the linearity of determinant, and the fourth one holds since $v_i$ forms an orthonormal basis.

Comment: can you please expand on why the first equality is true? (taking the inner product into the sum). I'm probably missing the obvious but I don't see how this follows from linearity...

Comment: @Nescio I added a line. It involves the linearity of inner product and the linearity of determinant. Is it clear now?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much! I really need a refresher...